# streaming video to the internet

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming

I want to stream my webcam live over the internet. It is mounted on a windows 7 desktop and connects to the internet over an ADSL connection. I am able to stream successfully within my home/office LAN using VLC (RTSP, RTP). I want to send RTP or RTSP packets from VLC to a server located in a data center and then stream those packets from the server? Is it possible to do so? If not, what are other possible means of streaming my webcam video live?

Appreciate your inputs and thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Ustream / Open Broadcaster Software (OBS)